# what's the difference between "past tense" and "past participle"?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles

For example,in this sentence:

> Begun in 1078, the Tower of London was built in London’s southeast corner by William the Conqueror.

Why does that sentence use *begun* not *began*?

Comment: *Began* is a finite verb, the past tense of *begin*.  *Begun* is not a finite verb; it is a past participle acting as an adjective, and so it has no subject; it modifies *the Tower of London*.

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

You can consider “begun in 1078” as an abbreviated form of the relative clause “which was begun”.

The issue really is the transitive verb “begin” versus the intransitive verb “begin”.

A.

> (Which was) begun in 1078

Here, begin is a transitive verb. Someone began the Tower of London. In fact, William the conqueror did. It was begun by him.

B.

> (Which) began in 1078

This would mean that the Tower of London just popped up out of nowhere by itself, which is impossible.

Comment: Yes, William **began** the tower then, and the tower **was begun** then.